# iPad 2 Chrome rendering issue

Tags: google-chrome, css, media-queries, screen-orientation, ipad-2

I currently have a site that is rendering properly in Safari for iPad 1 & 2 and properly in iPad 1 Chrome but Chrome for iPad 2 isn't picking up my media queries for portrait mode properly.

The css query I'm using:

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 979px)

This grabs all the other browsers without issue.  I've tried adding (orientation: portrait) to this and it fails to fix the issue with Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is just an idea: do not test in chrome! if it works in Safari, it will work in Chrome. I had the same issue and it took me more than an hour to find out that chrome won't clear your cached files even if your clear the browsing data

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the issue I'm seeing.  If I write the style outside of my media query it works in Chrome for iPad 2.  It just breaks the landscape version of the site for both versions of Chrome.  Although I have had issues with Chrome's caching while testing this so it helps to know that it isn't properly clearing the caches.

Comment: Update:  I deleted Chrome and Reinstalled and it fixed the issue.  Caching was definitely the problem.

Comment: let me just add an answer to the question, so that you can mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome in an iPad has issues with clearing the cache, even when using the option to `clear the browser data`. For now the best is not to use Chrome and use Safari instead. Most of the time,  the rendering in both will be the same.

Re-installing the Chrome app will temporarily clear the cache and fix the issue.